# what is the name of the logical type of a eth0 interface?

Tags: networking

docker0 is of logical type bridge, so what is the name of the logical type of a eth0 interface?

I have tried to list the eth0 with the following types in the below command

```
vlan | veth | vcan | dummy | ifb | macvlan | macvtap | can | bridge | ipoib | ip6tnl | ipip | sit | vxlan |gre | gretap | ip6gre | ip6gretap | vti
```

`ip link show type veth`

Comment: Related: [How to determine the logical type of a linux network device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/272850/86440).

Answer (score 3):

eth0 is a **physical** interface.  You won't be able to filter that type of interface from the output of "ip link show" using any of the **virtual** interface types.

Alternatively you might consider using NetworkManager to get a list of interfaces, like this:

```
$ nmcli device
DEVICE        TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
br0           bridge    connected  br0        
cni0          bridge    connected  cni0       
tun0          tun       connected  tun0       
virbr0        bridge    connected  virbr0     
enp4s0        ethernet  connected  br0-enp4s0 
vnet0         tun       connected  vnet0      
docker0       bridge    unmanaged  --         
veth6cfa9ab5  ethernet  unmanaged  --         
lo            loopback  unmanaged  --         
virbr0-nic    tun       unmanaged  --         

$ nmcli device | grep ethernet
enp4s0        ethernet  connected  br0-enp4s0 
veth6cfa9ab5  ethernet  unmanaged  --         

$ nmcli device | awk '/ethernet/ {print $1}'
enp4s0
veth6cfa9ab5
```